# RSpec test queries not working as anticipated but code/console work fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's my scenario.   I have a ticketing app that tests adding comments.   I have a creating_comments_spec set up that creates a user, creates a project and creates a ticket, has Pundit assign rights to it, then goes and visits.   Standard stuff.

Here's where I'm confused.

On my "show" page, I have the following controller actions for this newly created ticket:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:home]  


  def home
    @inactive_projects = Project.includes(:tickets).where(tickets: { project_id: nil} )

   @open_projects = Project.includes(tickets: :state).where.not({ states: { name: "Closed" } })
   @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

On my show page I loop through @inactive_projects and display a link to the project.name.   I do the same for @open_projects.   And for testing, I do it for @projects.

In RSPEC the only thing Capybara shows is the @projects = Project.all collection.   The other two come back empty.   If I create these in a let! block before everything, or using Project.create! and Ticket.create! before, during whatever, the ONLY thing that shows up is @projects = Projects.all.

This tells me that in some way my queries don't discover a Project that is there, though it should as the first finds all projects that have no tickets and the second finds all that have tickets that aren't closed.

And in my browser it all works.

And in the rails console, I can put all this in and create it JUST like the test and it all works fine.   It's only in RSpec that Capybara shows it's not finding anything by either collection I want.

I can put more, but as I said, I've adapted my test to do a million different things.   The ONLY thing that shows up in ALL cases is @projects = Project.all and NOTHING else EVER.   But in the browswer and console it all works.

Per the comment below, here's my spec:

```html
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Users can comment on tickets" do
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:project) { FactoryGirl.create(:project) }
  let!(:ticket) { FactoryGirl.create(:ticket, project: project, author: user) }
  
  before do
    login_as(user)
    assign_role!(user, :manager, project)
    FactoryGirl.create(:state, name: "Open")
    
    visit "/"
    click_link project.name
  end
  
  scenario "with valid attributes" do
    click_link ticket.title
    fill_in "Text", with: "Added a comment!"
    click_button "Create Comment"
    
    expect(page).to have_content("Comment has been created.")
    within("#comments") do
      expect(page).to have_content("Added a comment!")
    end
  end
  
  scenario "with invalid attributes" do
    click_link ticket.title
    click_button "Create Comment"
    
    expect(page).to have_content("Comment has not been created.")
  end
  
  scenario "when changing a ticket's state" do
    click_link ticket.title
    fill_in "Text", with: "This is a real issue"
    select "Open", from: "State"
    click_button "Create Comment"
    
    expect(page).to have_content("Comment has been created.")
    within("#ticket .state") do
      expect(page).to have_content("Open")
    end
    
    
      expect(page).to have_content("state changed to Open")
   
  end
  
  scenario "but cannot change the state without permission" do
    assign_role!(user, :editor, project)
    
    visit project_ticket_path(project, ticket)
    expect(page).not_to have_select("State")
  end
  
  scenario "when adding a new tag to a ticket" do
    visit project_ticket_path(project, ticket)
    
    expect(page).not_to have_content("bug")
    
    fill_in "Text", with: "Adding the bug tag"
    fill_in "Tags", with: "bug"
    click_button "Create Comment"
    
    expect(page).to have_content("Comment has been created.")
    within("#ticket #tags") do
      expect(page).to have_content("bug")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your spec look like? You said that you created a user, a project and a ticket, but did you also set the relations between them?

Comment: My model associations are right.   As I said, the code actually works in the console and browser running.   It just doesn't run in the RSPEC.   But, Project has many tickets.   Ticket belongs to state.   The queries in the controller above all work that I can tell.   Just not with Rspec.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see any *open projects* is probably because you don't have any in your test setup.

Your controller includes the following code:

```
@open_projects = Project.includes(tickets: :state).where.not({ states: { name: "Closed" } })
```

So, you should have a `project`, which is linked to at least one `ticket`. That ticket should be linked to at least one `state`, which name is *not* `Closed`. I don't see that anywhere in your spec.

You've created a `user` and `project` which you've associated with the `ticket` you've created on line 6. Where's the `state` though?

You do create a state in your `before` block:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:state, name: "Open")
```

But as far as I can see it's not associated to the `ticket` you've created previously.

The reason you don't see any *inactive projects* is (as far as I can see) because you don't have a `ticket` without a `project`. So, to fix that you could try this:

```
let!(:ticket_without_project) { FactoryGirl.create(:ticket, author: user) }
```

Comment: So, the default state is "New".   Every time a ticket is created it gets a status of "New".   The Open state created for the test is to show that when a comment is created if they change the state to "Open" it is reflected as "Open".   The test for a default state of new for every ticket is in the creating_tickets_spec.rb which I can show :).

Comment: Ok, so what do you get when you do `puts Project.all` in your `before` block right before `visit "/"`? Instead of `puts` you could indeed use `Pry` as Josh suggested. I want to know whether you have or don't have *inactive* and *open* tickets in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the pry gem and dumping a call to "binding.pry" into your spec, so you can run your spec line by line within the environment that's being set up.  I don't see anything wrong from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

This was my exact problem, and I assume you've already figured it out, but for me, the issue was that I had just changed the migration files for some of my models. Rails never complained about it, but my problem was solved after I rollback and migrate the test database, which you can do like so:

`rake db:rollback test` and `rake db:migrate test`

You may need to rollback x number of steps like so `rake db:rollback STEP=15 test`